Get image or video from tweet using tweet id or url (with a good rate limit)
I would like to replicate the https://twittervideodownloader.com/ using python, it get all the videos url

I tried to web scrap a tweet, but it loaded dynamically, so I discarded that option.
I'm trying to get it using Tweepy, it works but only 1 tweet/15 minutes.. that doesn't make sense to me.. How does that webpage do it?
Is there a way to get tweet info without that ridiculous rate limit?
